# Export Impala Table from HDFS to MySQL

Tags: mysql, hdfs, sqoop, impala, hue

I'm trying to use Sqoop to export an impala table from HDFS to MySQL. The table has already been made in MySQL and the schema of the two tables should match.

```
Impala table information: 
1   start_date  string  
2   start_station_code  string  
3   end_date    string  
4   end_station_code    string  
5   duration_sec    int 
6   is_member   int 
7   cnt bigint  

Impala table sample:
2019-05-05 14:07:42100022019-05-05 14:31:087143140611322
2019-05-08 17:51:57100022019-05-08 17:55:29705221101322
2019-05-05 14:07:40100022019-05-05 14:31:087143140711322
2019-05-07 09:55:48100022019-05-07 10:02:28672439911322
2019-05-03 06:54:38100022019-05-03 06:59:51705231201322
2019-05-07 09:56:33100022019-05-07 10:02:17705234311322
2019-05-05 14:06:40100022019-05-05 14:18:04642768411322
2019-05-01 08:54:36100022019-05-01 08:58:20705222301322
2019-05-02 09:17:22100022019-05-02 09:22:16692129401322
2019-05-02 09:16:37100022019-05-02 09:19:30705217201322
2019-05-06 07:09:54100022019-05-06 07:18:45608453111322

MySQL Table information:
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| start_date         | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| start_station_code | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| end_date           | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| end_station_code   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| duration_sec       | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| is_member          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cnt                | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+



Export code:
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/oozie --username root --password root --table bixirides_export --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/impala_out/6* -m 1 --input-fields-terminated-by "|";
```

For some reason the sqoop export fails as soon as the Map task reaches 100%. The schema should match properly, but for some reason the export fails.

```
Error Message:
ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export:
Export job failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of issues.. based on your qn

1. start and end date are varchar(10) but data size seems to longer than that. 
   2019-05-05 14:07:42
2. I see delimiter as | but don't see that in Hive table.

Did you create the table with

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS textfile